# Python 2.7 - Rpy2 Cox Proprotional Hazards Model

Tags: r, python-2.7, rpy2, cox-regression

I am using `Python 2.7` on `Mac OSX Lion` and will be installing `rpy2` to use `Cox Proportional Hazards Model`

I was just wondering: has anybody used `rpy2` to do Cox Proportional Hazards before.  I was reading some of the documentation on the `rpy2` package and it mostly talks about creating `dataframes` and such, as opposed to stating how various functions can be run.  So, how would I go about calling this function and then specifying the dependent `time variable`, as well as the `censoring` variable (designated by a binary `1` value)?

The R package for Mac also recommends that the computer not be connected to the internet when it is in use.  Why is that?