# Rpy2 - Function Calling - Cox Proportional Hazards

Tags: python-2.7, rpy2, cox-regression

My original post, which is currently unanswered and somewhat open ended, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278279/python-2-7-rpy2-cox-proprotional-hazards-model)

I have been trying to figure out how to work with this and will relate some sample data, where I have gotten to and what my current issue is.

So, my data, or rather a brief sample of my data, looks like this:

```
zipcode xcoord        ycoord    age_age6574 age_age75plus   sex_female  stage_late  death_death access  TruncTime
 51062  211253.4259 4733174.483     0           1               0             0         1           40      121
 51011  212255.621  4757938.874     0           1               0             0         0           43      121
 51109  215303.4471 4721047.303     0           1               1             1         0           21      121
```

This data has been preprocessed such that there exists dummy/binary variables in place of actual categories- `age_age6574` and `age_age75plus` make up one category, `sex_female` another, `stage_late` another, `death_death` another.  `Access` is a continuous variable. `TruncTime` will be treated as a discrete time variable.  The variable in that will be used as a censoring variable will be `death_death`.

Calling the functions:

So, to import everything I do the following:

```
 from rpy2 import robjects
 from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
 from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
 survival = importr('survival')
 coxph = survival.coxph
 Surv = survival.Surv
 theData = DataFrame.from_csvfile(newDataFile, header=True, sep=',')
```

So everything is all setup to do Cox Proportional Hazards - I think!

Within R I can do:

```
 coxph(formula = Surv(TruncTime, death_death) ~ age_age6574 + 
 age_age75plus + sex_female + stage_late + access, method = "breslow")
```

and everything works out fine.

When I do this same thing within Python, using everything I have described, I get an error that reads:

This is the function call:

```
  coxph(Surv('TruncTime', 'death_death'), 'age_age6574'+'age_age75plus'+'sex_female'+'stage_late'+'access', data = theData, method = 'breslow')
```

This is the error returned:

```
  Error in (function (time, time2, event, type = c("right", "left", "interval",  : 
  Time variable is not numeric
```

So, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong in the function call (why it is returning this error) and how I go about properly calling it?
Additionally, I'll also wondering if there is a way to change the `censoring` from a '0' to a '1' (reverse the way that the censoring variable works)?

::::UPDATE::::

So I found out part of my problem was specifying which columns/attributes to use.  Apparently, rpy2 needs numerical indices of columns to call the functions.  So:

```
 Surv(theData[9], theData[7])
```

for the survival part of the `coxph`.  The `Surv` part works.

Now, I'm still trying to work out how to specify everything else.  Namely:

-How do I specify the other variables to use in building the model.  There is a problem with using the `+` in linking these variables together.  Also `~` doesn't work as it does in regular R.  The following DOES NOT work

```
  coxph(Surv(theData[9], theData[7])~theData[3]+theData[4]+theData[5]+theData[6]+theData[8], data = theData, method = 'breslow')
```

I also tried replacing the '~' with a `,' such as:

```
  coxph(Surv(theData[9], theData[7]), theData[3]+theData[4]+theData[5]+theData[6]+theData[8], data = theData, method = 'breslow')
```

-It is definitely having a problem with those `+` and I'm not sure replacing the `~` with a `,` has actually worked.

Comment: Better to consolidate both entries on SO into _one_ entry (otherwise readers have to follow the breadcrumbs, in a way).

Comment: Without the exact Python code you are using to call `coxph()`, it is going to be difficult to guess what is happening....

Comment: @Igautier thank you very much for your replies!  Can you tell me the best way to consolidate?  Nobody had bothered to even comment on my previous post, so I didn't even think of doing that.  Right above the error I posted, towards the end of the post, is the code I'm using.  I will post an update and edit that so it is more prevalent and apparent.  Please take a look and if you have any ideas, definitely let me know!  Again, thanks for taking the time to read and comment!

Comment: Since no one commented on the other question, one way is to have all needed information in this question, and delete the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use a `Formula`.

Would this work ?

```
from rpy2.robjects import Formula 
coxph(Formula("Surv(TruncTime, death_death) ~ " \
              "age_age6574 + age_age75plus + sex_female + stage_late + access"),
      data = theData, method = 'breslow')
```

Comment: @Igautier thanks again for replying!  I'll give it a check and get back to you momentrily!

Comment: @Igautier I get an error `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Igautier oh! Actually I was putting it in the wrong place still (the very end, instead of the end of the `Formula`).  Now I get the error `invalid model formula in ExtractVars`.  Ideas?

Comment: @FortyLashes Single quotes should not have been there (answer is now edited).

Comment: @Igautier HA! YES! Thank you, so much, for taking the time to help me with this.  Now it is just a matter of formatting the results and putting them in a .csv file!  Again, thank you!